# Estimating the next prime in a random sequence

Tags: prime-numbers, data-analysis, distribution-of-primes

Is there a way (using statistics, or data analysis) to predict the nth term of a random sequence given the first k terms. For instance, what about predicting the $n$th in this sequence (random, appearing list of primes):

$p_n$ $=$ $2, 3, 11, 17, 23, 53, 79, 103, 197, 593, 971, 1021, 1663, 2099, 3571, 4447, 5419, 10781, 29347, 57901, 78517, 91129, 251893, 695407...$

(all terms less than $1M$ of this specific, random appearing sequence of primes)

Given $p_{24}$ $=$ $695407$ estimate $p_{70}$?

Is there a way to solve this sequence (find $p_n$ given the first 22 terms) with statistics and analyzing the behavior of it. In other words, there is an approximation formula for any single-set of sequcences to find any $n$th term greater than it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that your "random" sequence is strictly increasing and non-repeating?

Comment: It is the same idea and very similar distribution as this sequence: https://oeis.org/A000043

Comment: @J.Linne There is so little available data on Mersenne primes that I don't think a generic technique will prove very fruitful.  One might as well simply apply the map $p_n \mapsto n$ (which is by itself far more predictable) and ask about predicting the growth of an arbitrary *integer* sequence rather than asking about only primes.

Answer (score -1):

Well I can't say I know much on the subject, but given the fact that your sequence is 'random' and strictly of prime numbers less than 1M, there's probably not any way to do what you are asking. Sorry.

Comment: Of course I could be completely wrong. Who knows? I don't claim to be a mathematics expert, and I'm sorry if I'm giving that impression.

Comment: I'm using it for estimating large prime exponents $p$ in this sequence https://oeis.org/A000043 also my 'random' sequence has the same typical behavior as the oeis sequence above.